# Ruby Efficiency

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, performance

I was just listening to a lecture at coursera (https://www.coursera.org/saas/) and the professor was saying that everything in Ruby is an object and that every method call is calling a send method on an object, passing some params to it. This includes numbers, arrays and other basic classes.

I went on Google and looked for efficiency benchmarks and I found the following: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/which-programs-are-fastest.html

While it's not shocking that a compiled language is faster than an interpreted one, the performance difference between (Ruby, Python) and Java for instance is shocking.

Even if there's a way to compile ruby code (I have not researched this topic), I think the efficiency problem would still be there due to the core "problem" in the language:
Basic operations are being too heavy: 1+1 takes many more CPU cycles to complete.

I love Ruby. I love the high level aspect of meta programming and I think this is where the future should be heading, and I agree, sometimes we need to compromise certain thing in order to be more effective: I don't see myself optimizing my code in assembly in order to save a few extra milliseconds. However, when we do 1+1 in C, it's not exponentially increasing the amount of time a basic operation is taking!

My question is how are you guys dealing with operation intensive programs? We have a Ruby on Rails project we have been developing for about a year now and we're at a point we'll start doing some machine learning with geolocation traversal and prioritization.

I hope you understand my concerns and offer reasonable suggestions :-)

Comment: There's nothing exponential about the time it takes to add two fixnums in ruby. It's still `O(1)` (and adding two bignums is `O(log n)`).

Comment: 1+1 in Ruby looks for the type of 1, finds it's a Fixnum, looks up the + method in a lookup table, execute it and return the result. It took a few extra steps, which is a fixed number and theoretically, you are right, it's a O(1). Practically speaking, though, if every method does that, the time spent is growing "exponentially" (as I have observed in the benchmarks). I tend to differentiate between theoretical algorithm complexity and real-life algorithm complexity. Bucket sort is something to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort

Comment: No, if everything method does that, the time increase is linear. The runtime of a program doesn't double every time you add a method call. It increases by a constant factor. You can differentiate between theory and real life as much you want - "exponential" is still not a synonym for "large".

Comment: Please do not drop unrelated promotional links into post scriptums. You're only going to invite spam flags.

Comment: Sorry about the links. I am not affiliated with any of the sites or educational institutions that offer these free courses. I misused the word "exponentially" above (syntactically speaking, using the negation doesn't infer the opposite). What I care about is a solution. If you look at the benchmarks, there's no doubt there's a problem. It's totally unreasonable that something that takes 1 second with C would take 40 seconds. I'm not saying things to undermine Ruby. I love Ruby and it's the only language since LISP that I really love.. I just need a viable solution for our project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not such a bad question as it seems looking at the comments. The only problem is the wrongly used word *exponential*, but the described problem is real.

I have similar Ruby usage patterns as you describe - I'm doing a lot of natural language processing in Ruby, which involves machine learning as well. 
I use the following techniques to overcome Ruby performance issues:

1. Use C libraries with Ruby interface whenever applicable. E.g. I would not use Ruby implementation of SVM or decision trees, since there are much faster implementations in C available.
2. Write my own Ruby wrappers for C implementation if they are not available. Usually this is not much problematic - I use `RubyInline` gem extensively to glue Ruby with C code.
3. [Patch](http://blog.evanweaver.com/2009/04/09/ruby-gc-tuning/) Ruby memory management or manually control its garbage collector.
4. Consider [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) as your Ruby platform - you would get easy access to fast Java libraries for machine learning (Weka) and the like and general performance of your application would be preserved or even better.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Do you feel it's a practical thing to do or is it messy to have C code attached to your Ruby code in different places? Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: The basic idea is to cover all C code with nice Ruby interface and keep C codebase as small as it might be. If it turns out, that you have a lot of C code mixed with Ruby code, it is better to write separate C library, with its own tests. This makes the code much more modular and easier to maintain.